# Changing Lua Syntax to matlab

Tags: matlab, syntax, lua

I have some Lua code which I have to change into Matlab syntax and I'm really unsure how to proceed especially without any data to practice on, but at the moment since I just pasted the Lua code into Matlab I just want the Matlab errors to go away and hope I have something useable!

For some background, the full code is used to derive kinematic data from marker position coordinates recorded during gait analysis. It has been explained to me that the beginning of the code is basically getting the raw data, then the middle and end is transforming it.

The majority of the code is some basic maths which I managed to change but the beginning and the end is beyond the scope of my abilities.

Here is the beginning of the Lua code:

```
     --Initilisation of variables
ini = ini or 0
allinputs = allinputs or {}
input = input or {}
shapes = shapes or {"Sphere", "Cube", "Cylinder", "Cone"}
colours = colours or {"Red", "Green", "Blue", "White", "Gray", "White",     "Cyan"}

outputs.setchannels("gLLMx", "gLLMy", "gLLMz", 
                      "gLMMx", "gLMMy", "gLMMz", 
                      "gAJCx", "gAJCy", "gAJCz")

--Initialisation Code
if ini == 0 then

for i = 1, 38 do
    allinputs[i] = "Channel"..i
end

inputs.setchannels(unpack(allinputs))


ini = 1
end

for i = 1, 38 do
    input[i] = inputs.get("Channel"..i)
 end
```

and this is an example of some of the end of the lua code

```
if ZdistanceXZ == 0 then
ZrotZ = 90
else    
ZrotZ = math.atan(Zdy/ZdistanceXZ) * 180/math.pi
end
```

I'm obviously not expecting anyone to do any direct translating, I'm just hoping to get basic things explained to me. So far I got as far as changing all the " to ' and adding semi colons to the end of each line of the last part.
I'm just wondering if I need things like "then" and the "==" at the end of the code, the [i] at the top, and seeing if I need to change the brackets. Since I pasted the Lua code into Matlab I have a lot of "parse errors" so fixing these would be great. I'll use this information to write a code to derive kinetic data

Comment: What is the purpose of the 'setChannels()` method? I failed to find any documentation on it in the Lua official manual.

Comment: @Yellows this may be a D-flow thing, but I believe it basically sets each input as a channel, so input 1 = channel 1. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: I don't know what "D-flow" is, and I am left to think this is some kind of proprietary API - you should probably check if there is MATLAB or C/C++ support (as MATLAB can run C/C++ DLL). But I can explain which changes are needed in the rest of the code, if you wish

Comment: @Yellows Thanks for getting back to me, you're correct about D-flow it is an interface, I'm reading papers about this but my uni's developed this marker system so I'm assuming any code about it will be novel but keeping notes about useful information! However, explaining any changes by yourself would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Variables Initialization**

As far as I know there is no simple way to initialize this way in MATLAB. But the following code should do the job:

```
if ~exist('variableName', 'var')
    variableName = content;
end
```

You should do so for every variable. (I added a semicolon to prevent MATLAB from printing the resulting value - the automatic printing feature is usually used for debugging.)

**`setChannels()`, `get()`**

If this some kind of proprietary interface, then you should check if it has MATLAB. MATLAB also supports external functions in [several languages](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-external-functions.html).

**Loop and string manipulation**

```
% Initialisation Code - comments are written this way in MATLAB
if (ini == 0) % no need to write "then"

for i = 1:38 % 1:38 is a vector [1 2 ... 38]. this way the loop iterates 
                                                 % over every component
    allinputs[i] = [ 'Channel' num2str(i)]
end %end for

end %end if
```

Note that in MATLAB strings are between *simple* quotes. To convert a number into a string you need the `num2str()` function, as this is not done automatically. Concatenation of strings is done by putting the two strings in a vector (the square brackets) and separating the concatenated components by a space. The result is a vector of strings, i.e. a string.

**End of code and mathematical function**

```
if (ZdistanceXZ == 0) 
    ZrotZ = 90;
else    
    ZrotZ = atand(Zdy/ZdistanceXZ);
end
```

The function `atand()` automatically computes the inverse tangent in degrees (`atan()` computes it in radians).